# Interpreting a confusion matrix for a multiclass classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am struggling to understand why the image below classifies the third column of the first row as a true negative (typically true negatives exists on the diagonals of a confusion matrix as it indicates negative samples that were correctly predicted). rather than classifying it as a false negative as it is 'a' samples predicted as a 'c'.

[image]

Comment: Truly speaking, a confusion matrix is always 2x2 (TP, FP, FN, TN counts). It is about classifying a class of interest ("focal class"). Multiclass table of counts is just a crosstabulation.

Answer (score 3):

The green row, yellow column seem to indicate that the example is currently focusing on classification of class b versus the rest. The cell to which the arrow points contains the cases which were predicted to be not class b (class c was predicted), and were in fact not class b (actual class was a). These cases are thus correctly classified as not class b: true negatives.